# focus not working in editable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to navigate through tab key but focus() is not working.This is bootstrap table.here is my code.check last two lines.when i click on n number of cells and again navigate.it's working.

Table code:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tab1">
        <thead class="mbhead">
           <tr class="mbrow">
              <th></th>
              <th>A</th>
              <th>B</th>
              <th>C</th>
              <th>D</th>
              <th>E</th>
              <th>F</th>
              <th>G</th>
              <th>H</th>
              <th>I</th>
              <th>J</th>
              </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>asd</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>ddd</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
     </body>
    </table>
```

Edit code:

```
        function init(){

       $("#tab1 tr td:not(:first-child)").on("click", function (e) {
           console.log(e);
             mytd=$(this);//mytd is defined here
            if(e.currentTarget.contentEditable != null){
                 $(e.currentTarget).attr("contentEditable",true);
             }
            else{
                  $(e.currentTarget).append("<input type='text'>");
             }
          }); 

          $(this).keydown(function (event) {

             if (event.keyCode == 9){                       // tab key for navigation
                       event.preventDefault();
                       $(mytd).next('td').html("abcd");//working
                       $(mytd).next('td').focus();//cursor is not moving
                       return false;
                }
            }      
          }
```

thanx.

Answer (score 1):

In default, browser only make the elements focusable that are interactive, like buttons, links and input elements. To make other elements focusable you can use the `tabindex` attribute.

`tabindex` has a couple states:

- `tabindex="-1"` makes an element focusable, but not through the tab-key
- `tabindex="0"` makes an element focusable, and uses the default order when using the tab-key
- `tabindex="1"` and higher numbers makes an element focusable, the tab-key follows the order of the `tabindex` numbers

So in your case, I would choose to add `tabindex="0"` to the elements that have `contenteditable` enabled

Answer (score 0):

A `TD` element can't be focused.